# Coordinates on Android and Desktop reversed? (LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

The coordinates on my Android and my Desktop are reversed. In other words, (0,0) is the top left on Android, and bottom left on desktop. This is because I set:

```
    cam.setToOrtho(false, GateRunner.WIDTH, GateRunner.HEIGHT);
```

(Notice the false)

I already created my entire screen this way, so I can't change it back to true. Basically, I have a button, but when I tap it in the right place on my Android device, it doesn't work, even though it does work on the Desktop. On the Android, I have to tap it in a different place.

My touchDown():

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        float pointerX = InputTransform.getCursorToModelX(GateRunner.WIDTH, screenX);
        float pointerY = InputTransform.getCursorToModelY(GateRunner.HEIGHT, screenY);

        if(playButtonSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(pointerX, pointerY)) //Play button
        {
            game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));
            dispose();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

My InputTransform:

```
public class InputTransform {
    public static float getCursorToModelX(int screenX, int cursorX)
    {
        return (((float)cursorX) * GateRunner.WIDTH) / ((float)screenX);
    }

    public static float getCursorToModelY(int screenY, int cursorY)
    {
        return ((float)(screenY - cursorY)) * GateRunner.HEIGHT / ((float)screenY) ;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this so that the coordinate system stays the same - (0,0) on the bottom left - for both Desktop and Android?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use touch coordinates directly. You need to unproject them with the camera you're using with the SpriteBatch that draws the buttons.

```
private final Vector3 tmpVec3 = new Vector3();

public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    tmpVec3.set(screenX, screenY);
    camera.unproject(tmpVec3);
}
```

Now `tmpVec3` contains the touch location in camera coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this is the price to pay for multi - platform support.

I recommend you create a suitable abstraction, hiding the camera setup logic and have two different implementations for Android and Desktop. Hope it works.